# Inner Product and Orthonormal Basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the space of real-valued functions of the form $$a+b\ cos(x)+c\ sin(x), \ \ for\ \  a,b,c ∈ \mathbb R$$.Define $$ \langle f,g\rangle  = \int_0^{\pi}( f · g) dx$$ on $V.$

$(a)$ Find an orthonormal basis for $V.$

I am just confused on what is my $f(x)$ and what is my $g(x).$ I could not find any other examples that talk about the inner product in this format.

Comment: $f,g$ are just elements of $V$ means $f(x)=a+b cos(x)+c sin(x)$ and $g(x)=a^\prime+b^\prime cos(x)+c^\prime sin(x)$

Comment: So to find the orthonormal basis I would do ||a+bcos(x) + csin(x)||?

Comment: First find an orthogonal basis i.e. $f,g\in V$ s.t. $\int_0^\pi f(x)g(x)dx=0$ then normalize them

Answer (score 2):

Hint: a basis is $({1,\cos x, \sin x})$ then use Gram-Schmidt

Comment: Great hint! totally got it now thanks!